# Linked list without using collections in Java

Tags: java, linked-list, singly-linked-list

This is my Java program to insert an element in a linked list. I have written the following code:

```
import com.expanion.code.evalution.*;
public class Answer implements QuestionInterface {
    @Override
    public SchNode func(SchNode head, int index, char ch )
    {
        SchNode ptr;
        SchNode temp = new SchNode(ch);

        int count=1;


        for(ptr = head ; ptr!=null ; ptr=ptr.nextNode)
        {
            count++;
            if(index==count )
            {
                if(ptr.nextNode == null)
                {
                    ptr.nextNode = temp;
                    temp.nextNode = null;
                    ptr=temp;
                }
                else
                {
                    ptr.nextNode = temp;
                    temp.nextNode = ptr.nextNode;
                    ptr=temp;
                }
            }
        }
        return ptr; 
    }
}
```

While compiling it, the compiler shows that the loop has crashed. Since I am a beginner in Java, I haven't been able to find it.

Comment: If you are asking about a compilation error, then you will want to post the complete error message. No sense hiding this information.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Your problem is very unclear to me. Please give detailed description of the behaviour you observe. Quote any error message exactly. Is the problem (or symptom) present in your IDE now, or only when you try running the program? (I have never before heard of a compiler message about a loop having crashed, so I’m sceptical to the accuracy of that description.)

Comment: I am working on a  portal called expanion. The problem given to me is to insert an element in a linked list at a specific location. The inputs will be given by them manually and our part is to code only the function. And I have written the code but I'm not sure whether the code is correct. As of now when I run the code in the IDE given by them , an message displays that "the loop has been crashed for the given input". So I can't able to find where does the loop has crashed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see that this causes a cycle

```
 ptr.nextNode = temp;
 temp.nextNode = ptr.nextNode;
```

as temp.nextNode points to itself.

U need to interchange these lines